# Scientific notation in namelist with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I want to load a list from an input file via a namelist. To compile, I use gfortran:

```
PROGRAM main

IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: val,err
NAMELIST /myNamelist/ val

OPEN(100,file='input.txt')
READ(unit=100,nml=myNamelist,iostat=err)
CLOSE(100)

PRINT *, val

END PROGRAM
```

The input.txt looks like the following:

```
&myNamelist
val = 3e3
/
```

The program prints a 0 instead of 3000. If I plug in val = 3000 in the input file, it works. It seems that gfortran does not support scientific notation in a namelist. With ifort however it runs fine. Is there a workaround or something to use scientific notation in a namelist with gfortran?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `iostat=err`, but you do not check the value of `err`! If you did that you would found out that an error condition happened and `err` is nonzero. Therefore, `val` is of no use.

The scientific notation is not valid for integer input. Either read a `real` variable or do not use the scientific notation.

Try:

```
PROGRAM main

IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: val,err
character(256) :: msg
NAMELIST /myNamelist/ val

OPEN(100,file='input.txt')
READ(unit=100,nml=myNamelist,iostat=err,iomsg=msg)
CLOSE(100)

PRINT *, err
PRINT *, msg
print *, val

END PROGRAM
```

run:

```
> sunf90 intnml.f90 
> ./a.out 
 1083
 unexpected character in integer value                                           



 0
```

BTW, Intel Fortran accepts the value, but that is a non-standard extension. Your program would be non-portable if you relied on that.

Answer (score 3):

The draft of the 2008 standard that I have to hand states, at para 10.11.3.3.6, in the context of reading name lists:

> When the next effective item is of type integer, the value in the input
>   record is interpreted as if an Iw edit descriptor with a suitable
>   value of w were used.

In this case `gfortran` is doing no more than the standard requires while the Intel compiler goes a bit further and implements an extension that copes with a non-standard form of an integer value, *ie* `3e3`.

Comment: It's an extension. We're allowed. We allow any numeric type to be input to any other numeric type in list-directed or namelist input. gfortran and ifort are both correct. The input here is non-standard, so any interpretation is allowed.

Comment: Answer now modified to remove the aspersion cast on the Intel compiler.